# Let's get critical: Jan 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sustainable Living Stack Exchange](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: I apologize if this isn't the place for this a list of tags right next to tag box when posting a question would be great.  This would be great all over SE.  When I end up at an exchange I'm not familiar with sometimes I have no clue what tags are available!

Comment: @hortsu To request new features SE wide it's best to ask a question on [Meta Stackoverflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com). A [similar suggestion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/149220/164138) has already been proposed there, but so far no reaction from the SE developers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How do I dispose of Xenon light bulbs?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2317/how-do-i-dispose-of-xenon-light-bulbs)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Is it good to decompose plastic waste by burning?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/1294/is-it-good-to-decompose-plastic-waste-by-burning)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is Using Blankets to Insulate Doors and Windows Effective?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2315/is-using-blankets-to-insulate-doors-and-windows-effective)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Analysis of Water Usage by Family Demographics](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2319/analysis-of-water-usage-by-family-demographics)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Controling humidity of Vermicomposter in winter to prevent mold](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2321/controling-humidity-of-vermicomposter-in-winter-to-prevent-mold)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Should I take advantage of the higher heat pump COP during the warmest part of the day and "bank" heat in the house?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2350/should-i-take-advantage-of-the-higher-heat-pump-cop-during-the-warmest-part-of-t)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How to save heating energy with roommates?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2336/how-to-save-heating-energy-with-roommates)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Options to suggest to landlord for cost savings via renewable energy?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2355/options-to-suggest-to-landlord-for-cost-savings-via-renewable-energy)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can I estimate the gas usage of a pilot light?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2333/how-can-i-estimate-the-gas-usage-of-a-pilot-light)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Microbes used for home composting and cost effectiveness](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/microbes-used-for-home-composting-and-cost-effectiveness)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

Answer (score 2):

I think all this self-evaluation says is that we need more participation to benefit from it.